# RxJava - How can I set thread for observeOn dynamically?

Tags: android, multithreading, dynamic, reactive-programming

Let's say I have following code.

```
Scheduler ioSC = getIOThread(); 
Scheduler mainSC = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();

Subscription subs = getObservable()
                    .doOnNext(getAction1())
                    .doOnSubscribe(getAction2())
                    .observeOn(/****TODO***/)
                    .subscribe(getSubsAction());
```

In this code, I want to be able to set the thread for observeOn() based on the type if item I get from getObservable().
How can I add this condition checking in this subscription?
Is it even possible to dynamically set a thread for observeOn()?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `flatMap()` for this:

```
getObservable()
    .doOnNext(getAction1())
    .doOnSubscribe(getAction2())
    .flatMap(item -> Observable.just(item).observeOn(getScheduler(item)))
    .subscribe(getSubsAction());
```

But then the question comes up, **why** would you handle different items on different threads using the same subscriber. This seems a little off and you might want to **reconsider** your chain.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense :) The reason is that Observalbe items are basically the same kind with one boolean property that decides whether the item should be handled in a separate thread for computation or in the main thread for UI update in Android.